# Node js + Vercel : Not able to host index.mjs on Vercel (500 internal server error)

Tags: node.js, express, es6-modules, vercel, commonjs

I am creating an API service using Node.js and wish to deploy it on vercel. The application works perfectly fine on my localhost but gives a 500 error post deploying on vercel. It is because I have an mjs extension for my index.mjs. I am also using a package that needs commonjs to run.

Below is my directory structure

[image: Directory structure]

Below is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "apis",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.mjs",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"  },
  "type": "commonjs",
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "^2.2.0",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle": "^2.0.3",
    "@openzeppelin/contracts": "^4.7.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "hardhat": "^2.12.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "nft.storage": "^7.0.0",
    "web3": "^1.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20"
  }
}
```

and my vercel.json

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
      {
        "src": "index.mjs",
        "use": "@now/node"
      }
    ],
    "routes": [
      {
        "src": "/(.*)",
        "dest": "index.mjs"
      }
      
    ]
  }
```

My setup was hosting perfectly with the same configuration when I was using index.js instead of index.mjs. However, after adding functionalities I cannot avoid mjs.

Below is the error

[image: Internal Server Error]

Server logs

```
[GET] /
20:41:35:24
2022-11-03T15:11:36.500Z    undefined   ERROR   Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /var/task/index.mjs not supported.
Instead change the require of /var/task/index.mjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at /var/task/___now_launcher.js:26:28
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/___now_launcher.js:74:7)
    at _tryRequireFile (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:869:37)
    at _tryRequire (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:919:25)
    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:945:22)
    at Object.UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:976:27)
    at start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1137:42)
    at file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1143:7
    at async Promise.all (index 0) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.
It seems vercel has problems hosting ES6 modules. I was able to host this with heroku